# Confusing base conversion from bytes to hex

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

I'm having some trouble with this code. QByteArray::number should take the QByteArray from the hash and convert it to hex, but the result is much shorter than I expected. I was thinking that both outputs should be the same. I'm thinking it has to do with the pointer cast, but I don't understand what that cast is doing well enough to see how to value is made.

**Can anyone explain why these two lines output different results? Preferably in math terms.**

Code

```
QCryptographicHash hash(QCryptographicHash::Sha1);
hash.addData("some string to hash");
qDebug() << QByteArray::number(*(qlonglong*)hash.result().data(), 16);
qDebug() << hash.result().toHex();
```

Output:

```
"89bde3ca56c83c47" 
"473cc856cae3bd89e43ff9f62963d6f38372ccbd"
```

Expected Output:

```
"473cc856cae3bd89e43ff9f62963d6f38372ccbd" 
"473cc856cae3bd89e43ff9f62963d6f38372ccbd"
```

Note: My actual problem is in base 36, not 16, but there was conveniently a .toHex method to make this much easier to show.

Comment: At a guess, a `qlonglong` is probably 64 bits, which is quite a bit too small to hold a SHA-1 hash (160 bits).

Comment: JerryCoffin, I forget that c++ compilers assume you know what you're doing with pointers. So used to languages that wouldn't allow a cast that would truncate data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In you code `hash.result().data()` points at 160bit (20 bytes) of data. A `qlonglong` is 64 bits (8 bytes) of data on your platform.

`*(qlonglong*)hash.result().data()` reinterprets the first 8 bytes of the hash result as a number. Your platform is a little endian platform, so the first bytes of the hash data are interpreted as the low bytes of the resulting number.

As a result, the 64-bit number (viewed as hex) shows the first 8 bytes of the hash data in reverse order. You can see that in your output:

```
89 bd ... 3c 47
```

is the reverse of the initial part of

```
47 3c ... bd 89    e4 3f ...
```

Comment: makes sense. so glad I just assumed sha1 would fit into 64 bits. thanks

Answer (score -1):

You're essentially casting a `string` (as a `const char*`) to a `long long*`, then dereferencing it, and giving whatever numeric value you get back to the constructor of `QByteArray`.  Without using `qt` classes, you're doing this:

```
std::string s = "1b3";
const char* cc = s.c_str();

std::cout<<cc<<std::endl;
std::cout<<*(long long*)cc<<std::endl;
```

Do you get the same string back? No, you do not.

```
output:
1b3
3367473
```

It isn't a math thing... it's a problem with casting a `char*` to a `long long*` and expecting to have a valid numeric value as a result.

Comment: Apparently `hash.result` is not a string, but a class representing a byte sequence (probably `QByteArray`) so its `data()` method points to the raw binary data.

Comment: @JoergB I was confused by the `QByteArray::data`'s [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#data-1) which mention a "returned character string".  I think you're correct.